# creating a second image attachment template?

Tags: php, templates

Hi i am trying to create a second image attachment template. I have one, but I have created another. In the second one I want the attachments that are under a certain category of a post to have a different view from the rest.

Here is what i have in the nomrmal photo attachment page to try to call the category

```
<?php

$post = $wp_query->post;

if ( in_category('4679') ) {

include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/bet-photo.php'); 

?>
```

but the problem is, It's still showing the old attachment page and not the new one. What am i doing wrong.

Comment: Just use the same template, but do the `if/else` based on the category there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`attachment.php` is not the only template file for attachment display. mime-type based template files get priority.

> - MIME_type.php - it can be any MIME type (image.php, video.php,
>     application.php). For text/plain, in order:
>
>   1. text.php
>   2. plain.php
>   3. text_plain.php
>
> http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Attachment_display

I expect that that is the issue you are seeing. Check your theme for `image.php`.

There is a further problem with your code. Attachments don't have categories as far as I know. The category is inherited from the parent post. That means that you will need to pass the parent post ID to [`in_category`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_category).

```
if ( in_category('2', $post->post_parent) ) {
   get_template_part('bet-photo'); 
}
```

I would also suggest [`get_template_part`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part), as in my version of the code, instead of PHP's `include`.

Comment: This answer is timeless, many thanks for the insight on this topic.